# Hibernate JTDS / MSSQL JDBC driver problems with datetime column in SQL Server 2016 DB

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, datetime, jtds, mssql-jdbc

we recently upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 and a particular Hibernate/JPA bug went under our radar and is causing us quite a headache right now.

We are using Java with Hibernate (JPA 2.1) to interface with the DB.

The problem is as follows:

We have a table with a column of type **datetime** in it. At the end of our Java program we execute a named-update-query over hibernate where we have a condition on this column in the where clause:

```
datetime-column < :parameter.
```

The datetime column has always been mapped to a java.util.Date in the corresponding Entity. The parameter passed is also of type java.util.Date.

However, before the upgrade we were using the jTDS driver (and everything was working fine :)) but after the upgrade we decided to switch to the official microsoft driver. We made this move because the community seemed to indicate microsoft improved and maintained their driver over the years, whereas the JTDS driver has not been maintained for years...

We now face the problem that with the MSSSQL driver the provided java.util.Date parameter is passed as **datetime2** instead of **datetime** (as the JTDS driver did).

Because of this, the updatequery returns non-deterministic results (similar to this post: [JDBC driver sends Timestamp as datetime2 causing where clauses to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272833/jdbc-driver-sends-timestamp-as-datetime2-causing-where-clauses-to-fail)), which is why this bug went under our radar.

I tried to log the actual statement by setting the loglevel for org.hibernate.type to TRACE and even used https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy to log the actual statements, but it wasn't untill we profiled the DB Server over SSMS that we say the actual problem:

```
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 datetime2,@P1 datetime2',N'update PRODUCT 
set MARKETING_TEXT=null, version=version+1,
```

If we look at the same query executed wuth JTDS we see datetime params being passed instead of datetime2.

**My question is now:** we don't want to update the datetime column to datetime2. Is there some other way to configure hibernate in such a way that it sends the date parameter as datetime to the db insstead of datetime2?

Can somebody please point us in the right direction? I tried about everything including changing the datatype to calendar, implemnenting a custom UserType as described here (https://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/hibernate-date-vs-timestamp/), removing/altering the temporal annotation and even trying customize the SQL Server dialect to force passing of datetime instead of datetime2.

Nothing worked untill now (or I did it wrong), any suggestions?

**UPDATE 25.01.2018:**

To be more clear, i tried this:

```
public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {

    public CustomSQLServerDialect() {

        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");
    }
}
```

and defining a custom user type like this (copy pasted from a post with a similar problem to be honest):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class DateTimeUserType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.TIMESTAMP };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Date.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == y || !(x == null || y == null) && x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date(timestamp.getTime());
    }


    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.TIMESTAMP);
        } else {
            Date date = (Date) value;
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            st.setTimestamp(index, timestamp);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you find a solution using pure JDBC?

Did you try methods like:

PreparedStatement
    default void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, SQLType targetSqlType)

There probably is a vendor specific SQLType.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'll try to implement the query with JDBC and then debug the driver to see which SQLType works.

Comment: I debugged the query and it seems like a data conversion issue in the microsoft driver's PreparedStatement.setTimestamp() method. This problem is also discussed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/443. Currently no fix is available altough someone assigned the ticket to the "next tasks" milestone 20 days ago. Seems this bug is very fresh :)